# Skipping Animations in Robolectric 3.0+

Tags: android, android-animation, robolectric

If I have a test for a method that uses animations in robolectric, how do I skip forward to the point where animations are complete so the tests don't fail?

Answer (score 5):

We usually do it like:

```
Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().advanceBy(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
```